# Python not responding after executing plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib, crash, atom-editor

I am using the following code and python stops responding after executing `plt.show()`. I noticed removing the next input command removes the error, however, I need to retain both commands.

Next, I tried to sandwich `plt.pause(2)` between the two commands but here, python stops after I press any key once plot is displayed. Please help:

PS: I am using Atom editor with python 3.7.4

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def f(x):
    y=2.0*np.sin(x**2)+3.0*x-10.0
    return y
x=np.linspace(-5,3,100000)
plt.ion()
plt.plot(x,f(x))
plt.show()
plt.pause(2)
yy=input("pppp")
print(fsolve(f,2))
```

Comment: The code runs perfectly fine on my system. Are you running the code via IDLE or some other IDE? If you're using a different IDE, Try running it with IDLE

Comment: I am using atom

Comment: Try running in IDLE, Worked for me.

Comment: You could try adding `block=False` to `plt.show()`

Comment: I tried in Atom and had a similar problem. Without the pause statement, the plot doesn't show and the program seems to hang.  With the pause statement, the plot displays but the program still hangs.

Comment: This doesn't work in Jupyter lab using QT.  I don't want to use IDLE.  I hate inline graphs as they cannot be manipulated easily.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following line in your code plt.ion(). If I remove the parentheses from the end of the line the program seems to work fine in Atom.

Comment: `plt.ion()` enables interactive mode in the plot, removing the parentheses turns the line into an unused function reference - it would be clearer to simply remove the line entirely

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was just reporting the observations I made.

Comment: I assumed as much, but thought it might be worth noting in case someone comes across this answer without foreknowledge of what removing the parentheses will do